# How to code this if structure in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

can we code the following if condition inside the `<c:if test="${}`> ?

```
if((myFlag == true) && (flag1 != null || flag2 != null || flag3 != null))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<c:if test="${myFlag && (flag1 != null || flag2 != null || flag3 != null)}">
```

Simple, isn't it?

See http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref207.html#1010522 for a reference

Comment: oops quite simple.. I was just confused if we could nest conditions inside a test expression. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
<c:if test="${myFlag and (not empty flag1 or not empty flag2 or not empty flag3)}">
```

PS: Using a `null`-test to decide a flag instead of `true`/`false` is bad style and should be avoided, if possible.

Comment: I just used that as an example. Actual comparison has to be with a String value.

Comment: empty also returns true for empty strings (which are not null) and empty collections (which are not null)

Comment: @JB Nizet, thanks for the tip. Would have caused an issue for me.